# Share variable from directive to component Angular 2

Tags: angular

How can I pass a variable from a directive to a component?
I have a directive that tells where my mouse is on the screen and I want to share this somehow, A way that updates as the original variable updates. Basically how @Input decorator works when sharing between a child and parent component.

P.S. I don't want to use a service, there has to be a way with @Input or @Output right?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use a service? Publishing events to a service that exposes said events via observables would be perfect, and allow any part of the application to access it if they wanted.

Comment: Hmmm, I kind of forgot about observables lol. This is true.
If I can't find a better way, I may take this route

Comment: which is the parent component or how is the directive related to the component ?

Comment: Well the Component is the parent I guess (That defeats the purpose of a directive though, There isn't a parent)
The directive is used on the component though

Comment: Haven't used @Output yet myself (just a few months with angular2), but it might be good for your case :  http://learnangular2.com/outputs/

Comment: Yeah, i've used @Output before, but the way That I learned it is you have to bind the output inside the html, Directive don't have an html though lol.

Comment: I may end up using an observable if theres no other way

Comment: You should be able to use `@Output()` with directives, see [this project](https://github.com/orizens/angular2-infinite-scroll) for an example.